# Pepper Error 720

Tags: nao-robot, pepper, choregraphe

We have a Pepper robot recently and actively trying to develop apps for it. Lately more and more we encounter the same error - 720 (Indication for this error is that the shoulder LED's starts blinking yellow).

When we push the button we hear the following description of the error:

**Description:** Some of my motors are getting hot in my Neck. I will need to rest soon.

**Solution based on the documentation:** Robot motors are getting hot or are already too hot to be able to move. Put the robot in crouch and unstiffened and wait for few tens of minutes to let its motors cool down before you can use it again.

Is it normal that we encounter this error several times a day? When we push the button behind the tablet, the error goes away and we can continue our work.

The room temperature is about 22-24 degrees.

Is there something we can do to prevent this error from occurring?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Also check that you don't have objects near pepper (1m, 1m50 around pepper). If you do, then Pepper might consider those objects as potential kids and consistently try to look down to see them. With time it will heat up the neck because of the head's weight creating torque on the neck.

Comment: Actually I do. I've never considered that this could be an issue. I will try to remove then and see what will happen then. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Constant movement heats up the motor. If you do not need the robot to be alive or moving around when you develop then just put it in resting position.
http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-5/naoqi/motion/control-stiffness-api.html?highlight=relax#ALMotionProxy::rest

Answer (score 2):

If you encounter this error too often, the neck motor might be damaged.
You can contact support using this form: https://www.ald.softbankrobotics.com/en/about-us/contact . They will tell you if your Pepper needs repair.